# Accessing elements of updating form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I've got a form for updating a found item. The form extends Django's UpdateView through the views.  The forms for updating a lost item and for updating a found item use the same template but have separate views and forms.  They share the same template as majority of the fields are the same.

I am trying to add some custom form validation for the form for updating a found item in particular.  This validation is specific to the found item and does not apply to a lost item.  I have validation in a clean function in the `FoundUpdateForm` that checks to see if the needed conditions have been met and raises a ValidationError if a condition is not met.  Even though there is validation here, I want to add it in a JavaScript file as well.

I've tried creating variables in the JavaScript file tied to the elements on the form but have been unsuccessful.  I've tried using `var staff_type = document.getElementById('staff_type')`, `var staff_type = document.getElementById('FoundUpdateForm').elements.namedItem('staff_type')` and a few other variations of this.  The main issue that I'm dealing with is how to grab the form when it does not have an ID. I've looked into assigning the form an ID in forms.py but from my findings at least it doesn't seem like it could be done this way.

I want to avoid adding to the template as much as possible because as mentioned before, this template is used by multiple forms.  Additionally, because the form extends the UpdateView template, the template is able to use `{{ form.as_p }}` to render the fields for the form using p tags.  Because the elements are rendered to the page this way, Django assigns them each their own ID, but the form itself is not assigned one.

forms.py:

```
class FoundUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    Found._meta.get_field('staff_type').formfield(widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FoundUpdateForm, self).clean()
        staff_type = cleaned_data.get('staff_type')
        witness = cleaned_data.get('witness')
        res_type = cleaned_data.get('res_type')
        name_of_the_individual_claiming_item = cleaned_data.get('name_of_the_individual_claiming_item')
        phone_number = cleaned_data.get('phone_number')

        if not staff_type:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please fill out Type of Employee Resolving Item.")

        if staff_type == 'student' and not witness:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Student staff resolving lost items are required to have a witness.")

        if res_type.name == 'Picked up':
            if not name_of_the_individual_claiming_item:
                raise forms.ValidationError("If person is picking up item, the individual's name is required.")
            if not phone_number:
                raise forms.ValidationError("If person is picking up item, the individual's phone number is required.")
            if not witness:
                raise forms.ValidationError("If person is picking up item, a witness is required.")

    class Meta:
        model = Found
        fields = ['name_of_the_individual_claiming_item', 'phone_number', 'staff_type', 'witness', 'item_name', 'description', 'location', 'date_found', 'res_type', 'date_resolved']

        widgets = {
            'date_found': DateInput(attrs=date_attrs),
            'date_resolved': DateInput(attrs=date_attrs),
            'staff_type': forms.RadioSelect

        }
```

item_update.html:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load in_group %}

{% block content %}

<script src="{% static 'lostfound.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'admin/css/forms.css' %}">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  });

});
</script>

<fieldset class="well">
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
</fieldset>


{% endblock content %}
```

views.py:

```
class FoundUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Found
    template_name = 'lostfound/item_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('found_list')
    form_class = FoundUpdateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        item = form.save()
        LogEntry.objects.create(
                user_id         = self.request.user.pk,
                content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Found).pk,
                object_id       = item.pk,
                object_repr     = item,
                action_flag     = 2,
                change_message  = 'Update Found Item'
            )

        return redirect('found_list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FoundUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Change found'
        context['log_entries'] = get_object_history_list(self.model, self.get_object().pk)
        return context
```

Note: I am using Django 1.11

Comment: I don't understand your question. There's only one form on this page so your JS can just access it with `$("form")`. But if you really needed an ID why can't you do `<form id="myid"...>`?

Comment: Yeah that's a good point.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the form in a `<div>` and give that div a class, say `<div class="MySpecialForm">`. You can then find the (django-generated) form by referring to the form inside a div with that particular class (and if you want bulletproof, checking that it is unique). In general wrapping something in a div has no effect on its display, unless the div classes are special to something (such as Bootstrap). `$('div.MySpecialForm form')` (Or something close, I don't do JQuery selectors often enough to be a fount of knowledge on them! )

You don't need this unless there might be >1 form in the page, but if you are trying to write JS that's a general as possible, you should indeed allow for that possibility.

You should also consider templates and sub-templates, using a base template that defines the part that is invariant with respect to any one particular view and some empty blocks (or blocks displaying "Programming error, you forgot to override block foobar"). The sub-templates do

{% extends "wherever/whatever.html" %}
{% block something %}
stuff
{% endblock something %}
{% block something_else %}
etc...

And this neatly separates the specifics of one view from the generics of a particular sort of view.

Comment: Great thanks for the help! The thought of using a div to grab the elements didn't even cross my mind.  I like your solution, but I played around with it for a bit and discovered that I can access them using ```getElementById``` directly where I am using it and not assigning that to a variable.  I think I'm going to go with that way rather than your solution just so that I can entirely avoid messing with the template. I do like your advice about sub-templates and think that's a really good suggestion!